# VEGA Json url loading failed from Github

Tags: vega

I am failing to load my json file to VEGA online editor from github repository. VEGA DATA array below:

```
    "data": [
    {
      "name": "tree",
      "url": "https://github.com/omerakko/VEGA/blob/288ea5a5cc2a2e118eec6301f1b20288cffbef5b/vegaTreemapData.json",
      "format": {"type": "json", "parse": "auto"},
      "transform": [
        {"type": "stratify", "key": "id", "parentKey": "parent"},
        {
          "type": "treemap",
          "field": "percentage",
          "sort": {"field": "value"},
          "round": true,
          "method": {"signal": "layout"},
          "ratio": {"signal": "aspectRatio"},
          "size": [{"signal": "width"}, {"signal": "height"}]
        }
      ]
    },
    {"name": "testData", "source": "tree"},
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [{"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.children"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "leaves",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [{"type": "filter", "expr": "!datum.children"}]
    }
  ],
```

github directory is set to public.

I get a [warning] loading failed message.
Am I missing a configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: the answer is about correctly using github.
`"url": "https://github.com/omerakko/VEGA/blob/288ea5a5cc2a2e118eec6301f1b20288cffbef5b/vegaTreemapData.json"` points to the html page, not to the json file.

Solution: replace "url" link by clicking to " raw " button available for the file in github to access unpreprocessed data